# Flat links with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What code can I use to have flat links with htaccess?
An example of what I want:

site.com/folderA becomes : site.com/index.php?section=folderA

site.com/folderA/folderB becomes : site.com/index.php?section=folderA&action=folderB

site.com/folderA/folderB/folderC becomes : site.com/index.php?section=folderA&action=folderB&id=folderC

I tried it with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?section=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?section=$1&action=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?section=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `$` (line end anchor) to avoid matching unwanted URL parts:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request is not for a file/directory 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
# then skip from rewrites
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1action=$2id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: yup. what is that for?

Comment: That is there to match either `site.com/abc` OR `site.com/abc/`

Comment: When I include the ?, and then in index.php echo $_GET['section'], it prints "index.php" on the screen

Comment: that is because rewrite rule is executing twice. See updated answer now to prevent that condition.

Comment: This helped, but if I go to site.com/section/action/id/someextrastuff, instead of going to the error page it gives the value "404.shtml" to the parameter "section"

Comment: Is `site.com/section/action/id/someextrastuff` an existing file/directory?

Comment: nope. Always when I put four or more slashes in the url (site.com/section/action/id/someextrastuff, or site.com/section/action/id/someextrastuff/anotherfolder/yetanotherfolder/), it sets the value of section to 404.shtml

Comment: There is no rule in your .htaccess for 4 or more slash. Your last rule can handle 3 slashes.

Comment: I know, but what should my code be if I want to redirect the user to the 404 page instead of setting the value of section to 404.shtml?

Comment: That will be a line like this: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I managed to do it with this: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([*])$ index.php?section=404 [NC,L,QSA]`, and then handle the error in the php script itself